# How can I temporarily create an external Spanned drive big enough to make a backup of another external 5 TB HDD which seems to have been unallocated

Tags: ssd, windows-11, array, external, spanned

I have a Dell laptop 2n1 running Win 11 which I use as a desktop (never leaves my desk) and had a 5 TB WD Elements HDD that I was using for backup's, as well as secondary storage for large media files (like .mov files, etc.).

I have many blank 1 TB SSD USB drives all over my home office to be (mistakenly) able to make a temporary Spanned drive/volume on a hub to recover the 5 TB HDD files to, so that I could try to restore this. It would only be temporary after which I'd reformat the USB drives to their original format to use normally.

Now that I've discovered how near impossible this would be, I guess I'll have to find a drive recovery service or buy another WD Elements 5 TB drive (I don't think so right now)! Any recommendations?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: drive recovery services are far far more expensive than a 5tb drive where I live so I'd just buy a drive. Downside is that you may need drive recovery services after all. Maybe borrow a drive?